# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The address has an invalid host name

Tags: c#, email, unicode, web-config, smtp

I have already tried almast everything but it keeps giving me this message while all the information is correct( I think so).

This is the Error:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The address has an invalid host name:
>   yakovmora1@gmail.com‏.
>   System.ArgumentException: Invalid Unicode
>   code point found at index 9. Parameter name: strInput at
>   System.Text.Normalization.Normalize(String strInput, NormalizationForm
>   normForm)

my code in ASPX.CS is:

```
  protected void Sbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {     
        string Name = Request.Form["Name"];         
        string email = Request.Form["email"];
        string message = Request.Form["Message"];
        if (CheckFields(Name, email, message, ref  Label1) == true)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage myEmail = new MailMessage()
                {
                    Subject = "Message from website user: [" + Name + "]",
                    Body = "Email: " + email + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message,
                    IsBodyHtml = false,
                    From = new MailAddress(email, Name),

                };

                myEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("yakovmora1@gmail.com‏", "IsraeCoreLx‏"));

                SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient();
                server.Send(myEmail);
                Label1.Text = "Message Sent";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = "error sending message <br/><br/>" + ex.ToString();
            }
            if (Label1.Text != "Message Sent")
            {
                Label1.Text = "trying again";
                #region trying again
                try
                {
                    MailMessage myEmail = new MailMessage()
                    {
                        Subject = "Message from website user: [" + Name + "]",
                        Body = "Email: " + email + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + message,
                        IsBodyHtml = false,
                        From = new MailAddress(email, Name)


                    };

                    myEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress("yakovmora1@gmail.com‏", "IsraeCoreLx‏‏"));

                    SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient();
                    server.Port = 25;
                    server.Send(myEmail);
                    Label1.Text = "Message Sent";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "error sending message <br/><br/>" + ex.ToString();
                }
                #endregion
            }
            if (Label1.Text == "Message Sent")
            {
                CleanFields( Name,  email,  message ,ref Label1);
            }
        }

    }


    private void CleanFields(string Name, string email, string message, ref Label Label1)
    {

       Request.Form["Name"] = "";
        Request.Form["email"] = "";
        Request.Form["message"] = "";

    }



    private Boolean CheckFields(string Name, string email, string message, ref Label Label1)
    {
        if (Name != "")
        {

            if (IsEmailValid(email) == true)
            {
                if (message != "")
                    return true;
                else
                    Label1.Text = "Your message is empty.";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Your email is invalid.";
            }
        }


        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Please fill in your Name.";
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Boolean IsEmailValid(string EmailAddr)
    {
        if (EmailAddr != null || EmailAddr != "")
        {
            Regex n = new Regex("(?<user>[^@]+)@(?<host>.+)");
            Match v = n.Match(EmailAddr);

            if (!v.Success || EmailAddr.Length != v.Length)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException:
The address has an invalid host name: yakovmora1@gmail.com‏.

System.ArgumentException: Invalid Unicode code point found at index 9.
Parameter name: strInput

at System.Text.Normalization.Normalize(String strInput, NormalizationForm normForm)
```

Taking a look at this string: `yakovmora1@gmail.com`

The 9th character is `1`, which seems fine to me, but I see that you're embedding it directly within your source-code (a very bad idea, but nevermind). Are you saving your `*.cs` files with the right encoding? Make sure you use UTF-8 or UTF-16 (Visual Studio > <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Advanced Save Options</kbd> > <kbd>Encoding</kbd>).

Comment: what you mean by saying ,a very bad idea? where you want me to write it?

Comment: Anything that can change, such as email addresses, connection strings, usernames, passwords, hostnames, etc should be stored in a separate user-editable configuration file. You can use `app.config` and `<appSettings>` for simple key/value storage.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that before sending the email you watch the mail message value in the debugger, or call "ToString" method. In this case, under .NET 3.5 or earlier, there is a bug which changes a field value within the mail message object that causes this failure later.

I also encounter a similar bug, and resolved it. You can see the details here:
[MailMessage "From" property assignment indirectly causes exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558176/mailmessage-from-property-assignment-indirectly-causes-exception)

Hope that this will help you!