# MailMessage "From" property assignment indirectly causes exception

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first question on StackOverflow!

However, I solved the problem (by accident), but don't really understand the strange behavior.

The following code fires an exception:

```
...
MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("my@email.address", "my display name (in hebrew)");
ms.From = from;
...
```

The exception I get is:

```
"Failure sending mail."
(The inner exception message is: "An invalid character was found in header value.")
```

However, If I assign the new instance directly to the "From" property (as you can see in the following code fragment), everything works as expected.

```
...
MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();
ms.From = new MailAddress("my@email.address", "my display name (in hebrew)");
...
```

Does any one have any idea?

Thanks :-)

**Edit 1: Steps to reproduce**

As @ShadowWizard suggests, it is hard to reproduce this problem using a clean console application. Hence I will try to investigate what is going on in my application that causes this strange behavior.

Comment: Are you able to post the Hebrew display name?

Comment: Nope, that's can't be it. It's like someone trying to force open a stuck lid of a bottle. He tries once, twice, thrice and always fail. Then he tap on wood three times, try again... and the lid pops open. Was it the tapping on wood that caused a "miracle"? No. It was pure coincidence, he just used different angle/more power. Same in your case. When you changed the code to `ms.From = new MailAddress(...)` you changed something else as well, that solved that error.

Comment: @cgatian The Hebrew text is "בזק החברה הישראלית לתקשורת בעמ"

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wrote such a code some months ago, and last week I had to add some features, so I wrote this code fragment and It was always failed. I Tries to change every single piece of the code, piece by piece - nothing solved the problem. Finally, when I looked back at the "old" code I noticed that this was the only difference. Now, everything works fine - this is the only change I made to the code, nothing more!

Comment: @Ilan believe me, there is something. My best bet is the code that failed contained quotes: `בזק החברה הישראלית לתקשורת בע\"מ` and you removed the quotes in the new code, solving the error by this. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard There is really nothing, however I solve the issue...

Comment: Think better leave it, as I highly doubt anyone can reproduce it.

Comment: Did the string come directly from the source code, or was it loaded from the database / configuration file?

Comment: @M.A.Hanin, It does not matter. However I managed to reproduce this issue as well as understand how to avoid it (see my answer below). Because this is my first question on StackOverflow, I can accept my own answer only in two days.

Comment: Alright, thanx for the reply. I was interested in this issue since I'm also sending emails under Hebrew names, but never had any problem with that - was curious what the cause is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,

Now I know how to reproduce this issue as well as how to solve it (or more excatly how to avoid it).

To reproduce, create an empty .NET 3.5 console application and copy the following code.

```
namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        private static SmtpClient _smtp = null;
        public static SmtpClient Smtp
        {
            get
            {
                if (_smtp == null)
                {
                    _smtp = new SmtpClient("relay.your-smtp-host.com", 25);
                    _smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                }
                return _smtp;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MailMessage ms = new MailMessage())
            {
                var from = new MailAddress("from@email-address.com", "**THE NAME MUST CONTAINS SOME NON ANSI CHARS**");

                string s = from.ToString(); /* This is the line - comment it and everything will work fine! */

                ms.From = from;
                ms.To.Add(new MailAddress("recipient@address.co.il"));
                ms.Subject = "Here is my message title";
                ms.Body = "Here is my message body";
                Smtp.Send(ms);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. To reproduce the issue, you must put some NON ANSI characters within the DisplayName property.
2. Run this program once without break points, then comment the line **string s = from.ToString()** and run again.

As you can see, if the "ToString" method is called prior to the call to Smtp.Send, an exception is thrown.

**Well, I ran into this problem in the first place because I run the application with break points, so the debugger call the ToString() method behind the scenes.**

(To make things more clear, simply put the line:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(from)
```

before the call to Smtp.Send, then move it after the call).

Question:

What is the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer:

Is comes out that within **.NET framework 3.5** there are two methods within MailAddress class that set an internal field named **"fullAddress"** in two different ways.

The first method is ToEncodedString():

```
internal string ToEncodedString()
{
    if (this.fullAddress == null)
    {
        if ((this.encodedDisplayName != null) && (this.encodedDisplayName != string.Empty))
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            MailBnfHelper.GetDotAtomOrQuotedString(this.encodedDisplayName, builder);
            builder.Append(" <");
            builder.Append(this.Address);
            builder.Append('>');
            this.fullAddress = builder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.fullAddress = this.Address;
        }
    }
    return this.fullAddress;
}
```

The second method is ToString():

```
public override string ToString()
{
    if (this.fullAddress == null)
    {
        if ((this.encodedDisplayName != null) && (this.encodedDisplayName != string.Empty))
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            if (this.DisplayName.StartsWith("\"") && this.DisplayName.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                builder.Append(this.DisplayName); 
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append('"');
                builder.Append(this.DisplayName);
                builder.Append('"');
            }
            builder.Append(" <");
            builder.Append(this.Address);
            builder.Append('>');
            this.fullAddress = builder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.fullAddress = this.Address;
        }
    }
    return this.fullAddress;
}
```

Now, within SmtpClient, when sending the message, it triggers the settings of "From" header:

```
this.Headers[MailHeaderInfo.GetString(MailHeaderID.From)] = this.From.ToEncodedString();
```

which in turn triggers the following method:

```
public override void Set(string name, string value)
{
    if (Logging.On)
    {
        Logging.PrintInfo(Logging.Web, this, "Set", name.ToString() + "=" + value.ToString());
    }
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
    }
    if (value == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }
    if (name == string.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("net_emptystringcall", new object[] { "name" }), "name");
    }
    if (value == string.Empty)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString("net_emptystringcall", new object[] { "value" }), "name");
    }
    if (!MimeBasePart.IsAscii(name, false))
    {
        throw new FormatException(SR.GetString("InvalidHeaderName"));
    }
    if (!MimeBasePart.IsAnsi(value, false))
    {
        throw new FormatException(SR.GetString("InvalidHeaderValue"));
    }
    name = MailHeaderInfo.NormalizeCase(name);
    MailHeaderID iD = MailHeaderInfo.GetID(name);
    if ((iD == MailHeaderID.ContentType) && (this.part != null))
    {
        this.part.ContentType.Set(value.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), this);
    }
    else if ((iD == MailHeaderID.ContentDisposition) && (this.part is MimePart))
    {
        ((MimePart) this.part).ContentDisposition.Set(value.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), this);
    }
    else
    {
        base.Set(name, value);
    }
}
```

This method validates that the header value contains only ANSI character before sending it through the network (because of SMTP protocol limitations). But the "fullAddress" field was already set with non ANSI characters by a call to ToString(). Hence the sending was failed due to exception, saying that there are "Invalid" characters in the header.

After looking in the reflected code of .NET 4.0 it seems that this issue was solved by totally rewriting the internal implementation of MailAddress!

Thanks for trying to help!

P.S.
@ShadowWizard As you can see, sometimes there is nothing :-)

Answer (score 0):

We had this issue but only when the sender name was read from the configuration file. The issue was not reproducible with code only.

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2008/09/smtpclient-exception-invalid-character.html

The solution was to set the subject encoding in an explicit way.